# How to loop a div and get the text in the paragraph tag only using BeautifulSoup and python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am using beautifulsoup and python to crawl a web page and extract the text from the paragraph tag only from the website.
[This is the page I want to crawl](https://www.who.int/csr/disease/coronavirus_infections/faq_dec12/en/) 
I want all the texts in all the paragraph tag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us some code !

Comment: Update the question with text based HTML and code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use selenium as you last resort to save your resources .

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.who.int/csr/disease/coronavirus_infections/faq_dec12/en/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
  driver.get(url)
  div_text = driver.find_element_by_id('primary').text
  with open('website_content.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(div_text)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
finally:
  if driver is not None:
    driver.close()
```

You can achieve the same thing with requests and beautiful soup as follows :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response  = rq.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
  div_text = soup.find('div',{'id':'primary'}).text
  with open('website_content.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(div_text)
```